# on NextJS How to prerender shared components of my site?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, layout, next.js

I have a site built with nextjs with a top navigation bar and a footer. Since those are the same on every page, I didn't add them to their individual js files under pages/, instead, I have a 'wrapper' that adds those to each page. The data of both come from a JSON (2 different languages).

I was trying to use getServerSideProps but that won't work because the navigation bar itself is not inside the page.

What is the 'correct' way of doing this? I cannot hardcode the JSON in the code because it might change and I would prefer not to have to add those sections on the code of every page I have.

I see that the nextjs is preparing a release with the possibility to get static props in _app.js but what is the current solution for this problem?

_app.js

```
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <AppWrapper>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </AppWrapper>
  );
}
```

in AppWrapper I create the app context with react hook (createContext) and then wrap it

```
const WebWrapper = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <main>{children}</main>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: This is a very old pet peeve of next.js – see this long discussion: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/10949 . It is promised to be solved in some future version by new layouts api (I am not sure if it is available ATM). https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/10949#discussioncomment-2706819 worked for me after some customization (although it could seems somewhat intimidating).

Comment: You can either use `getInitialProps` in `_app` and fetch the data for the navigation from there; or fetch the data directly in the component inside a `useEffect`.